# Generation function of recurrence sequence

Tags: functions, sequence

I'm trying to find generation function of recurrence sequence

```
ClearAll[c];
c[1] := 0;
c[2] := 1;
c[n_] := (2 + 2*(n - 2)*c[n - 2] + (n - 2) (n - 1) c[n - 1])/(n (n - 1));
Table[c[i], {i, 1, 15}] 
FindGeneratingFunction[%, x]
```

but *Mathematica* just output

> ```
> FindGeneratingFunction[{0, 1, 2/3, 5/6, 4/5, 37/45, 52/63, 349/420, 338/405, 
>                           873/14175, 14554/17325, 157567/187110, 466498/552825, 
>                           11994551/14189175, 41582906/49116375}, x]
> ```

How I can find `GeneratingFunction`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `y[x]=Sum[c[n]x^n,{n,0,Infinity}]` be the generation function of `c[n]`.
Then `y[x]` satisfys a 2rd order ODE `(1-x)y''[x]-2xy'[x]-2/(1-x)==0`. Try to find solution with `DSolve` and the result is

> ```
> y[x] -> (1 + C[1] E^(-2x))/(1 - x) + C[2] - (2 C[1] ExpIntegralEi[2 - 2 x])/E^2
> ```

We have initial conditions `y'[0]=c[1]=1, y''[0]=2c[2]=2*1=2`. Thus,the undetermined coefficents(upper case `"C"`) `C[1]` and `C[2]` will be obtained immediately by adding them to the `DSolve` function above.

However *Mathematica* returns

> ```
> "DSolve::bvnul:For some branches of the general solution, the given boundary
> conditions lead to an empty solution."
> ```

That error massage means `C[1]` or `C[2]` can't be determined. This may be due to the value of `c[0]`, `c[1]` and `c[2]`. Turn to the recurrence relation, then we get `c[2]=(2+0*c[0]+0*c[1])/2=1`.

That is to say, `c[1]` and `c[0]` can be any value!! No wonder that we can't find a proper solution to that ODE.

By the way, you will get a result of `c[n]` (a long long expression involved n) by inputing following command

```
RSolve[{c[n] == (2 + 2*(n - 2)*c[n - 2] + (n - 2) (n - 1) c[n - 1])/(n (n - 1)), 
        c[1] == 0, c[2] == 1}, c[n], n]
```

Comment: Thank you! I found it already http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539078/generating-function-of-recurrence-sequence/539084?noredirect=1#539084

Answer (score 3):

I realise that it is not the answer for your question about generating function but it may help a little.

I will abuse the fact that you do not ask *why*. I have no experience with this area in *Mathematica*. But using documentation I was able to  find a solution.

That's what is the best in *Mathematica*!

For your list, I've added an iterator so it will fit `FindSequenceFunction`

```
list = Table[{i, c[i]}, {i, 1, 15}] 

f = FindSequenceFunction[list]
```

> ```
> DifferenceRoot[
>     Function[{y, n}, 
>              {-2 - 2*n*y[n] - n*(1 + n)*y[1 + n] + (1 + n)*(2 + n)*y[2 + n] == 0, 
>              y[1] == 0, y[2] == 1}]]
> ```

```
 Array[f, 15] == Array[c, 15]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: I didn't notice you hit 10k, congrats!

Comment: @rcollyer I don't know why I have not seen your comment earlier :/ Thanks! :)